# Adding value to array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to add values from one array to another array after making some calculation, here I did it using for loop but I want efficient way doing so. Please help me.. thanx

```
from numpy import *

arr = array([1,2,3,4,5])

arr1 = []

for i in arr:

    arr1.append(i+5)
    
print(arr1)

nArray = array(arr1)

print(nArray)
```

Output :

[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[ 6  7  8  9 10]

Comment: Simply do `arr1 = arr + 5`. Numpy broadcasting will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanx Gilad Green

Answer (score 1):

You should have just done:

```
nArray = arr + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

For a builtin Python [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), you can use a list comprehension:

```py
arr1 = [x + 5 for x in arr]
```

Since you are using a [numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array) however, you can just add 5 to the array with:

```py
arr1 = arr + 5
```

Comment: Remove the first part. It's correct but not efficient for numpy.

Comment: Thanx Thomas Saint